# How to retrieve data (URLs) from Google Sheets and use it in a javascript code for redirecting from a page to the retrieved URL?

Tags: javascript, url, google-sheets, redirect

I don't have huge knowledge regarding coding so please help me out with this. There is a website with some hyperlinked text (actually a time table for attending classes) in it. That table has many links which are subject to change regularly. What I want to do is, when the texts are clicked, it should open an empty html (redirecting page) that sends users to google meet. I am regularly changing the code in it and I became a bit lazy. So, I had an idea to make a Google Sheet in which I add all the links and those links will be retrieved by some code. Then those they can be used in my redirecting pages which redirects to google meet app. How can I make this work? If answered It would help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to give you correct answer.
How is your website served? Via Google Apps Script as Web App? If not, using Google sheets as database might be the wrong option for you.

Comment: Im using firebase as the server